# customizing x and y axis in corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am interested in modifying a correlation table I made with corrplot.
[image: correlation table]

I would like to modify it so all the numeric categories are on the X-axis and the letters are on the y-axis. Is there anyway to tell it which categories I want on each axis? Below is my R code.

```
library(corrplot)
blinded <- read_excel("corralation.xlsx", sheet = "blinded")
corr <- cor(blinded, method = "pearson")

cor.mtest <- function(mat, ...) {
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  n <- ncol(mat)
  p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
  diag(p.mat) <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):n) {
      tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], ...)
      p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
    }
  }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat)
  p.mat
}

p.mat <- cor.mtest(corr)
head(p.mat[, 1:5])

col <- colorRampPalette(c("#EFFF00", "#228B22"))
corrplot(corr, method="color", col=col(200),  
         type="upper", order="hclust", 
         addCoef.col = "black", 
         tl.col="black", tl.srt=45, 
         p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.01, insig = "blank", 
         diag=FALSE)
```

Comment: try plotting with type="lower", see if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, instead of flipping the table, I am interested in only having 1:4 on the x-axis and removing the letters while removing the numbers from the y-axis and only having letters of this axis.